# Single responsibility principle on complex process

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I always had a question on how to assure the single responsibility principle when the process I have to assure is quite complex.

I work with a 3 layers architecture Backend: Controller (my API endpoints) | Service (single responsibility functions) | Data (access to the DB)

Let's say I have a process `ProcessA` that is composed by 4 tasks `TasksA1`, `TasksA2`, `TasksA3`, `TasksA4`.

If I have an endpoint exposed on my controller layer such as: `POSTMethodProcessA`

How should be composed my code in order to respect the single responsibility principle on my service layer?

The options I see:

**Option 1** (the controller must know the process):

```
class MyController {
  exports.processA = functions.https.onRequest(req, res) => {
    myservice.doTaskA1(); // single responsability on task1
    myservice.doTaskA2(); // single responsability on task1
    myservice.doTaskA3(); // single responsability on task1
    myservice.doTaskA4(); // single responsability on task1
  });
}
```

**Option 2** (the service know the process and loose the Single responsibility)

```
class MyController {
  exports.processA = functions.https.onRequest(req, res) => {
    myservice.doProcessA();
  });
}

//inside the service (the doProcessA method must be in charge of multiples tasks and loose the single responsability principle :
class MyService {
  function doProcessA() {
    this.doTasksA1();
    this.doTasksA2();
    this.doTasksA3();
    this.doTasksA4();
  }
}
```

This question is even more complicated to me if the tasks are composed themselves by multiple jobs: `FirstJobA1`, `SecondJobA1`, `ThirdJobA1` ...

How those complexities layer should be handled on the code structure to respect the single responsibility principle is something that always blocked me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common misconception is that `Single Responsibility Principle` means that a class
(or service or a system, etc.) should do only one thing. Instead, SRP means that
the subject must have a **single reason to change**.

Thus it's fine to have separate "service" implementations for each task,
and then an "aggregate" service that orchestrates the whole process:

```
service TaskA;
service TaskB;
service TaskN;

service Process{
    TaskA::run();
    TaskB::run();
    ...
    TaskN::run();
}
```

A change in a task should not affect unrelated tasks. Also, a change in the
process should not affect the subtasks. This is related to the *Common Closure
Principle (CCP)* which states:

> The classes in a component should be closed together against the same kind of changes. A change that affects a component affects all the classes in that component and no other components.

or more informally:

> gather into components those classes that change for the same reasons and at the same times

This means that if a change in `TaskA` will inevitably lead to a change in `TaskB`,
then maybe those two should be a single task, instead of two.

Apply that recursively to your sub-tasks: `FirstJobA1`...`FirstJobA-N`

Comment: Thank you so much on that one. You made it much more clear to me. 
A function in my service can handle multiples functionnalities as long as they are all linked together when a change should appear (if i change one functionnality in the list, all other should change too).
You changed my conception of this architecture a lot !!!! Thank you so much